# php: remove excess <br> and tags from a string

Tags: php

how can I remove excess `<br> and &nbsp;` tags from the start and end of a string?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('{^(<br(\s*/)?>|&nbsp;)+}i', '', $str); //from start
$str = preg_replace('{(<br(\s*/)?>|&nbsp;)+$}i', '', $str); //from end
```

that also gets XHTML `<br />` and `<br/>` forms

Comment: doesn't seem to pick up multiple line breaks

Comment: works for me with this: $str = '<br><br>this is a test<br><br>';  Can you give me an example of a string it doesn't work with?

Comment: you are right.. didn't realize my display function was performing nl2br.  Thanks!

Comment: You probably have to do &amp;nbsp;

Comment: I had the same problem. Tried &amp;nbsp; but it preserves the string exactly the same. It seems to be converting   only.

Comment: @ThomasW.: thanks for the edit. it seems Stack Overflow has fixed whatever parsing issue was present 5 years ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

With [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = "<br>some text&nbsp;"
$str = preg_replace('/(^(<br>|&nbsp)*)|((<br>|&nbsp)*$)/i', '', $str);
```

Didn't test it, but something like that should work.

Comment: I get unknown modifier for /g

Comment: I don't think you need /g in PHP...?

Comment: You're right, that's not a search but a replace... I'll change that now, sorry.